# MLR Package R - Confidence Intervals and store Imputation

Tags: r, machine-learning, confidence-interval, mlr

The Reviewer of my manuscript recommended splitting my healthcare data in the training/test set. On the training set, I should use a nested wrapper by amputating and filtering my variables (chi quadrat 10 variables) on the inner loop. After building my best Model there I should access it on the Test-set.

He wished that the imputation of the training-set was stored and used on the test-set. He also wished me to report the confidence intervals of the performance measures (especially the balanced accuracy).

```
    task = makeClassifTask(id = "db",data=trainDB,target = "y")
    inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)
    lrn = makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type ="prob")
    lrn2 = makeImputeWrapper(lrn, list(numeric = imputeMean (), factor= imputeMode()))
    filter = makeFilterWrapper(lrn2, fw.method ="FSelector_chi.squared", fw.abs = 10, resampling = inner)
    outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)
    r = resample(learner = filter, task = task, resampling = outer,measures = list(bac,auc,tpr,tnr, ppv, npv), models = TRUE, show.info = FALSE)
```

**Question:**
Is my main code ok? which commands can I enter to store the imputation and calculate the [confidence-intervals](/questions/tagged/confidence-intervals)?

Thank you.

Comment: You are not tuning any hyper parameters?

Comment: (1) mlr is deprecated, please use mlr3 for new studies. (2) You know that the reviewer is male? (3) Based on how you phrased your question I see lots of error potential since you seem to be somewhat new to modeling. Don't try everything at once and try to understand what you are doing and why you are doing it. Just following a reviewers advice is not always the best way to go. And suggesting a chi_squared filter wrapper without hyperparameter tuning seems at least "questionable".